# Cloudbees Identity Management

Tags: authentication, cloudbees, identity-management

Is there an identity management mechanism available to control/manage user access to a service running on the cloudbees RUN@cloud platform i.e. force log in / sign up etc?

Thanks,
/W

Comment: Are you asking about login for administrators to do things like suspend the application or control its resources, as Nicolas answered? Or about login for users of the application?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in replying. yes, I am wondering about implementing a basic authentication/login for users of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Users you added to your cloudbees domain ("account") can access all services. For a FOSS account, resources are accessible read-only without authentication, but in all other cases login to the platform is required. 
Only administrators can subscribe to new services. Jenkins on DEV@Cloud adds RBAC plugin so you can control fine-grain access to jobs and folders.

Comment: So this is answering a different question than was asked.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no special support from the CloudBees platform for authentication of users of your application: this is just something you would implement in your app using any of numerous available libraries according to language and web framework, using the authentication system of your choice such as OpenID.

Comment: "this is just something you would implement in your app using any of numerous available libraries according to language and web framework".. what would you recommend for Java? ... I have been looking at solutions such as OpenAM but this is a major overkill for my needs! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should consider Identity access management solutions from [TeleSign](http://www.telesign.com/products-demos/). You should be able to control user access to services running on Cloudbees Run@cloud platform with ease.